# How to create a json array from these json objects in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I have a dictionary that looks like this.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"cpu" : self.proData ,
                           @"date" : timeMilliString,
                           @"memory" : self.memData,
                           @"battery" : self.batData,
                           @"deviceID" : @"1"
                          };
```

I'm creating json objects from it like this:

```
self.jsonObj1 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
self.jsonObj2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
self.jsonObj3 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Afterwards I want to put the 3 json objects into a json array and then put that json array into another json object. So finally, it should look something like this:

```
{"mobileData":[
        {   "cpu":-991,
            "date":"142441374.5834",
            "memory":978,
            "battery":-96,
            "deviceID" : 2
        },
         {  "cpu":-51,
            "date":"142441374.5834",
            "memory":978,
            "battery":-96,
            "deviceID" : 2
        },
        {  "cpu":-51,
            "date":"142441374.5834",
            "memory":978,
            "battery":-96,
            "deviceID" : 2
        }

    ]
}
```

I have tried it as follows but it's not working.

```
NSArray *jsonArray = @[self.jsonObj1, self.jsonObj2, self.jsonObj3];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"mobileData" : jsonArray};
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
        {
            // Serialize the dictionary
            json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error2];

            // If no errors, let's view the JSON
            if (json != nil && error2 == nil)
            {
                NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonString);
                //[jsonString release];
            }
        }
```

I'm getting an exception.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: try googling u will find solution

Comment: @JayGajjar I'm new to iOS dev so do you mind telling me what exactly to google?

Comment: @JayGajjar I have searched for this but only come across examples of parsing json and not actually creating a new json.

Comment: @danb add all 3 dictionary into array and use that array into one dictionary as key mobileData and your json structure is ready.

Comment: @Prince Thanks for your reply. Is this the correct way to add the 3 dictionaries into an array: `NSArray *jsonCombined = @[self.json1, self.json2, self.json3]` ?

Comment: @danb no don't use json object but use simple dict object you created to add to array. What here i mean is only once we will use to create json object not 4 times.

Comment: @Prince Thanks. I now have dict1, dict2, dict3. I'm combining using: `NSArray *jsonCombined = @[dict1, dict2, dict3];` then `NSDictionary *finalJson = @{@"mobileData" : jsonCombined};` Is this correct? I now have to convert my finalJson to a NSData for that post method right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly add all dictionaries to a array.

```
NSMutableArray *mutArrData = [NSMutableArray array];
//Add dictionaries which vary to your requirement.
[mutArrData addObject:yourDictionary]; //1
[mutArrData addObject:yourDictionary]; //2
[mutArrData addObject:yourDictionary]; //3
```

Now create a main dictionary to add array.

```
NSDictionary *dictJsonData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[mutArrData mutableCopy],@"mobileData",nil];
```

Now create json from dictionary

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJsonData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

if (jsonData && !error)
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonString);
}
```

Comment: @dand Atlast  I have answered your question so you can make it without error.

Comment: Error on line `NSDictionary *dictJsonData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[mutArrData mutableCopy],@"mobileData" nil];`  saying `Called Object type NSString is not a function or function pointer` and `mobileData` is highlighted.

Comment: Forgot , in the line so replace NSDictionary *dictJsonData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[mutArrData mutableCopy],@"mobileData",nil];

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting the correct data format (which works perfectly in Postman). Just that it doesn't work with the post method you helped me with earlier.